# Cmake Qt5 | undefined reference to `QPrinter::QPrinter(QPrinter::PrinterMode)

Tags: cmake, qt5

I am preparing cmake build for qt application. where I am using following structure ..

libMyApp
which uses

```
SET(QT5_MODULES Widgets PrintSupport Network XmlPatterns)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${QT5_MODULES})
```

and

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
    ${TARGET_NAME}
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::PrintSupport 
    Qt5::Network
    Qt5::XmlPatterns
)
```

libMyApp build successfully and generated libMyApp.a (static library)

Now I am using this library in my application MyApp
which uses

```
SET(QT5_MODULES Widgets PrintSupport XmlPatterns)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${QT5_MODULES})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
    ${TARGET_NAME}
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::PrintSupport 
    Qt5::XmlPatterns
    ${CODE_LIB_FILES}
)
```

${CODE_LIB_FILES} is list holding path of libMyApp.a
MyApp builds successfully and at last shows linking error

```
undefined reference to `QPrinter::QPrinter(QPrinter::PrinterMode)
```

Same thing happening with xml also

```
undefined reference to `QDomNode::isElement() const'
```

can anyone point out what is wrong here ?

or any sample program depicting same scenario with printsupport and xmlpatterns module

Comment: As an idea try to link your `${CODE_LIB_FILES}` rigth as the next entry to `${TARGET_NAME}`. The order of the function `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES()` is important. The last entry shall have no dependencies. So the Qt5 libs should be linked last.

Comment: Thanks Frodo, that was the issue, it is working now :)

Comment: You are welcome, to complete this request I also answered your question in a post ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the entries in the function `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES()` is important. The libraries with no dependecies shall be mentioned last which are typically some standard libraries or external libraries, in this example the Qt5 Libs.

An example:

- Application depends
- `Lib_A` depends on `Lib_B` and `Lib_std`
- `Lib_B` depends on `Lib_std`
- `Lib_std` has no dependencies

Then the call of the function shall be the following:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
    ${TARGET_NAME}   # Name of the app
    "Lib_A"
    "Lib_B"
    "Lib_std"        # Last entries: Std Libs, external Libs, ...
)
```

In this application I assumed that `${CODE_LIB_FILES}=libMyApp.a` has some dependencies to the Qt5-Libs so it would be plausible to move this entry above the Qt5-Libs.

```
SET(QT5_MODULES Widgets PrintSupport XmlPatterns)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${QT5_MODULES})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
    ${TARGET_NAME}
    ${CODE_LIB_FILES}       # <<< Moved this entry up
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::PrintSupport 
    Qt5::XmlPatterns
)
```