# CLion and Qt5: tuning qmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5, clion

I have a set-up as explained elsewhere, e.g. [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-setup-CLion-to-work-with-the-Qt-framework). I have `Qt5` installed system-wide,
and have the requisite lines in my `CMakeLists.txt`. My IDE is Clion.
Everything in a simple GUI goes fine until I add `Q_OBJECT` macro (I want this to connect signals to slots). Now, when I do this, I get the `undefined reference to vtable`-type error,
that is also found in abundance on the net.
My confusion arises from the fact that some recommend using `Qt5`-bundled `cmake` for your project,
which essentially means "just for GUI" I need to change the toolchain. But some actually say nothing about it. What all say is that

> Qt runs qmake every time Q_OBJECT is added/deleted

Now, how to capture that in my `CMakeLists.txt`? -- the relevant part thereof is given below.
I've seen`moc` and `qmake` inside `/usr/lib/qt5/bin`; so how to communicate this to `CLion`?

```
# ----- GUI part -----
# Qt5 inclusion
# The meta object compiler is one of the core functionality of Qt, it reads a C++ header file and if it finds a
# Q_OBJECT macro, it will produces a C++ source file containing meta object code for the class.
# It's the mechanism that allow signal and slots to work.
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{QT_DIR}/$ENV{QT_VERSION}/gcc_64/lib/cmake)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/lib/qt5/bin/)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
# Enable user interface compiler (UIC)
# The user interface compiler is a program that read XML from the .ui file
# generated by Qt Interface Designer and generate C++ code from it.
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.7.0")
    set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
endif()

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /usr/lib/qt5)
# @see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994603/cmake-qt5-undefined-reference-to-qprinterqprinterqprinterprintermode
SET(QT5_MODULES Widgets PrintSupport)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS ${QT5_MODULES} REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/qcustomplot)
add_executable(gui
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui/main.cpp
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/qcustomplot/qcustomplot.cpp)
set_target_properties(gui PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_link_libraries(gui
        PUBLIC
        Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets qcustomplot)
```

Never mind the verbose comments; my initial GUI training being in `Java Swing`, I found them useful.

EDIT: what helped me was the `qt5_wrapper_cpp` thing mentioned in
[Qt 5 cmake fails with undefined reference to vtable on hello world with inc & src as subdirs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761767/qt-5-cmake-fails-with-undefined-reference-to-vtable-on-hello-world-with-inc-sr)

Answer (score 1):

`Q_OBJECT` macro requires code generation. That's why you got `undefined reference` exceptions. I don't remember exactly how to configure a cmake project for Qt, but I would recommend reading https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-qt.7.html.

Something like `set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES AUTOMOC TRUE)` should help you.