# Qt5 and CMake: cannot find Quick, QuickControls modules

Tags: qt, cmake

I have the following set-up:

```
$ qmake --version
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.9.5
```

I am using `CMake` with the following relevant instructions (to give you a context):

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/lib/qt5/bin/)

if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.7.0")
    set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
endif()

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /usr/lib/qt5)
# @see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994603/cmake-qt5-undefined-reference-to-qprinterqprinterqprinterprintermode
SET(QT5_MODULES Core Widgets PrintSupport)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS ${QT5_MODULES} REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(HW_GUI_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui)
# include_directories(${HW_HEADER_DIR})
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
...
```

The core part is

```
SET(QT5_MODULES Core Widgets PrintSupport)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS ${QT5_MODULES} REQUIRED)
```

Now, when I add `Quick` or `QuickControls2` into the `QT5_MODULES`, `CMake` cannot find those,
and I see this error on the cmake-config step:

> CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28
>   (find_package):   Could not find a package configuration file provided
>   by "Qt5Quick" with any   of the following names:
>
> ```
> Qt5QuickConfig.cmake
> qt5quick-config.cmake
> ```

Now, not to confuse you, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin` seems to be a symlink
to `/usr/lib/qt5`, which I've checked like this:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Oct 30 18:00 fixqt4headers.pl -> ../../../qt5/bin/fixqt4headers.pl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Oct 30 18:00 moc -> ../../../qt5/bin/moc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Oct 30 18:00 qdbuscpp2xml -> ../../../qt5/bin/qdbuscpp2xml
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Oct 30 18:00 qdbusxml2cpp -> ../../../qt5/bin/qdbusxml2cpp
```

How to fix this error and find the `Quick` module? What is special about it -- I am able to load the other modules allright.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, please check if you have installed the correct packages providing those modules. Since you seem to be using some Debian derivative, these are the package names that you should install: qtdeclarative5-dev and qtquickcontrols2-5-dev. See:

https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/qtdeclarative5-dev/filelist

https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/qtquickcontrols2-5-dev/filelist